# Determine if $f(z) = \log(e^z+1)$ is analytic and where

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I tried to substitute $z$ with $x+iy$ and then write it down as $f(z) = log(e^xcis(iy)+1) $ but it looks worse than the starting point. on original branch

Comment: Analytic where?  The composition of analytic functions is analytic.  But you have to be careful with $\ln$: what branch are you using?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Actually it's a warmup problem for my next week exam, and i'm hell of a newbie to this section, so i think the point is to determine where is analytical area of this function.

Comment: @RobertIsrael after reading my note i think your answer is $-\pi \lt \theta \le \pi$

Comment: Convert $e^z+1$ to a form $re^{i\theta}$  Then $ln$ will be $ln(r)+i\theta$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I couldn't find a way to write it like that. after going further with what i have in the post I managed to write $cis(iy) = ch(y)-sh(y)$ which has no $i$ in it and i'm totally confused

Comment: $e^z+1=e^xcosy+1+ie^xsiny$, $r^2=(e^xcosy+1)^2+(e^xsiny)^2$, $\theta=arctan(\frac{siny}{cosy+e^{-x}})$.   Check Caucy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Ok imagine that i did, then i have to check where does the analytic area of two function intersect?!

Comment: @herbsteinberg I still can't find $u$ and $v$ to do the Cauchy-Reimann

Comment: Look at previous comment.  $u=ln(r),\ v=\theta$.

Comment: $\theta$ has two possible values.  To get the correct one, use $sin\theta = \frac{e^xsiny}{r}$ and $cos\theta=\frac{e^xcosy+1}{r}$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the branch of logarithm that is analytic on the complement of the left half-line $B = (-\infty, 0]$.  So your function is analytic at $z$ as long as $e^z+1 \notin B$, i.e. $e^z \notin (-\infty, -1]$.

Now if $z = x + i y$ with $x, y$ real, $e^z = e^x e^{i y}$.  For this to be in $B$, you need $y = (2n+1) \pi$ with for integer $n$ (so that $e^{iy} = -1$) and $x \ge 0$ (so $|e^z| = e^x \ge 1$).  Thus your function is analytic on the complement of
the half-lines $y = (2n+1) \pi$, $x \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Summary of previous comments plus.

Convert $e^z+1$ to a form $re^{i\theta}$ Then $ln$ will be $ln(r)+i\theta=u+iv$ for Cauchy-Riemann equations to check analytics.  $e^z+1=e^xcosy+1+ie^xsiny$.  Therefore  $r^2=(e^xcosy+1)^2+(e^xsiny)^2$, $\theta=arctan(\frac{siny}{cosy+e^{−x}})$.

For Cauchy-Riemann you could use $u=\frac{ln(r^2)}{2}$.  Also note that although $\theta$ has two possible values, they differ by a constant ($\pi$), so it doesn't effect the analysis.

Comment: I can't find relation between $r$ and $\theta$ so i could write function as $u(r,\theta) + iv(r,\theta)$

Comment: $ln(e^z+1)=ln(r)+i\theta$.  Therefore $u=ln(r)=\frac{ln(r^2)}{2}$ and $v=\theta$

Comment: Aha Cauchy-Reimann is always correct for the $ln(r)+i\theta$ now we have to check where does $ln(r)$ available for $r^2 = (e^x\cos y+1)^2+(e^x\sin y)^2$ and check domain of $\arctan(\frac{\sin(y)}{\cos(y)+e^{-x}}) $ and we are OK right?

Comment: I mean $ln(r)+i\theta$ is analytic everywhere except $0$ and negative $x$ axis

Comment: This ends up as $z=x+i\pi$ with $x\le 0$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the determination of logarythm you saw, you should know on which domain the complex logarithm is holomorphic. 
The question would be : can the function exp(z) + 1 go outside of this domain ?

Comment: actually i better asked determine analytical area.

Comment: Then the question would be the following: for which z does exp(z) + 1 belong to the analytical area of the logarithm?

Comment: I think that's correct, and ln(z) is analytic in all of  the plane but $x\le0$ right? for the original branch

Comment: That depends on the determination of argument you chose, but I think you chose the usual one, so it's correct.

Comment: so now i should use function composition or sth? or is it possible to do it with the Cauchy-Reimann equation?

Comment: With function composition, it will be fine. By the way I'll add a comment: I find the notation $ln$ a bit confusing for the complex logarithm